# Error:(7, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'google()' Possible MyPartyPlot' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method. \

Tags: java, android, gradle

Error:(7, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'google()'
Possible causes:

The project '1BookMyPartyPlot' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin

solve with android studio 1.3.2

Comment: where is the code?

Answer (score 0):

The `google()` repository was introduced with recent versions of the Gradle plugin and Android Studio. You will need to upgrade to the newest version to be able to use this. As of this writing, Android Studio is at version 3.x.

The alternative with older versions of Android Studio is to install a local version of the Google Repository. I do not know how much longer Google intends to support this, so you should upgrade to a modern version of Android Studio.